# The closure of all periodic homeomorphisms of circle

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $X$  be the space of  all continuous  maps  from $S^{1}$ to $S^{1}$. $X$ is  equipped with $C^{0}$ topology. Let $Y\subset X$ be the union of all  finite order homeomorphisms i.e:  all homeomorphisms $\phi$ with $\phi^{n}=Id$ for  some natural number $n$. Assume that $g\in X$ belongs to $\bar{Y}-Y$. Some  questions  about such $g$:

1.Is $g$ necessarilly a  homeomorphism?If yes, is it necessarilly order preserving?

2. Is it true to say that $g$ satisfies at least one of the following conditions:

I: The periodic points of  $g$ is  dense

II: $g$  has  a  dense orbit

More  generally, to what extent, the elements of $\bar{Y}-Y$ are known, dynamically?

What  about if  we replace $S^{1}$ with another manifold and study the elements of $\bar{Y}-Y$? What  about if we consider $C^{k}$ topology for $k>0$?

**Note:** A possible operator theoretical version for  question $1$ could be the following:Let $A$ be a  $C^{*}$ algebra. Let $X$ be the space of all unital morphisms and $Y\subset X$ be the union of all finite order automorphisms. Assume that $T\in \bar{Y}-Y$. Is $T$ necessarilly an automorphisms.(Actually, is it surjective?)

Comment: If it is indeed the case that $g$ is a homeomorphism, then [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number) should help you with $2)$.

Comment: @Hachino  thanks for your comment. Is the situation similar to $g=$ irrational rotation? Is there an example of a $g$ for which periodic orbits are dense, in contrast to irrational rotation? Could you please more explain on your comment?

Comment: I don't know, that's just something your question reminded me of. I am no expert in DS, sorry.

Comment: @Hachino Any way, thank you for your comment:)

Comment: @AliTaghavi notice that if periodic orbits of $g$ are dense, then $g\in Y$. In fact, any periodic orientation-reversing homeo has period $2$, and hence there is no orientation-reversing map in $\overline{Y}\setminus Y$. On the other hand, every periodic orbit of an orientation-preserving homeo has the same period. So, any $g$ with dense periodic orbits must be periodic itself.

Comment: The elements that are not in the closure of the periodic elements, they're things like homeomorphisms that have some non-empty fixed-point sets, but the fixed point set is not the entire circle.  So on the intervals between the fixed points they're shift operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to both questions 1 and 2 is false, due to the following example.
Consider $(n+1)$ consecutive intervals $I_0,...,I_n$ of lengths $1,2,4,...,2^{n-1}, 2^n$. Let the map $T_n$ cyclically permute them in an affine way. In fact, if you choose $I_j=[2^j,2^{j+1}]$, then 
$$
T_n(x)=\begin{cases}
2x, & x \not\in I_{{n}}\\
2^{-n}x, & x\in I_{n}.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, make an affine change of the coordinates so that the union $I_0\cup\dots\cup I_n=[1,2^{n+1}]$ becomes (always the same) circle $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$. Then, the constructed maps on this circle $C^0$-converge, as $n\to\infty$, to
$$
T(x)=\begin{cases}
2x, & x \in [0,1/2]\\
0, & x\in [1/2,1].
\end{cases}
$$

This map is not a homeomorphism (it collapses the interval $[1/2,1]$ to a single point 0). Also, the orbit of any point falls to the fixed point 0 in a finite number of steps, so there is only one periodic point, and there is no dense orbit.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Lets imagine these $I_{j}$ as arcs in the unit circle. So it seems that you fix $I_{0}$ at whole upper hemi circle, $I_{1}$ approachs to the whole lower hemi circle, and the remaining $I_{j}$'s are limited to the small remainig part. So it seems that the familly $T_{n}$'s is  not  an equicontinuous familly of  maps. So this  contradicts to uniforms convergence. So  could  you please more explain about your construction?

Comment: In the other words, are you sure that $T_{n}$,  $C^{0}-$ converges to $T$?

Comment: In fact the last acr $I_{n}$ is very small for large n,  and is mapped to $I_{0}$ which has a fixed size. so we loose equicontinuity.Am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry, but yes, you are: the length of $I_n$ is $2^n$, not $2^{-n}$, so this is almost half-circle arc, not very small one. On the other hand, $I_0$ has length 1 in a circle of length $2^{n+1}-1$, so it is a very small arc.

Comment: I  appologize for my  misunderestanding. Now I underestand your counter example.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to Question 2 is no. In fact, there is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism $g\colon \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g\in\overline{Y}\setminus Y$ and such that it has exactly one fixed point (consequently, it has no dense orbit and it is not periodic):

For each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\tilde g_t\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $\tilde g_t(x):= x + 1/8(1-\cos(2\pi x))+t$. Notice $\tilde g_t$ is the lift of a circle homeomorphism $g_t$. Let $g=g_0$ and observe $0\in\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the only fixed point of $g$.

We want to show that $g\in\overline{Y}\setminus Y$. To do this, let $\rho_t=\rho(\tilde g_t)$ denote the rotation (also called translation) number of $\tilde g_t$. Observe that $\rho_t$ depends continuously on $t$ and 
$$ \rho_t > \rho_0=0, \quad\forall t>0.$$

In particular, this implies that there exists a strictly decreasing sequence $(t_n)$ with $t_n\to 0$ such that $\rho(t_n)$ is a Diophantine (irrational) number. Hence, by Herman-Yoccoz linearization theorem (see for instance https://eudml.org/doc/82144), for each $n$ there exists a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism $h_n\colon\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $h_n\circ g_{t_n}\circ h_n^{-1}=R_{\rho_{t_n}}$, the rigid rotation of angle $\rho_{t_n}$. Then one can choose a sequence of sufficiently small positive real numbers $(\epsilon_n)$ such that $t_n+\epsilon_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ and 
$$h_n^{-1}\circ R_{t_n+\epsilon_n}\circ h_n\to g, \quad \text{in the } C^\infty\text{-topology}.$$

Finally, since $t_n+\epsilon_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have that $h_n^{-1}\circ R_{t_n+\epsilon_n}\circ h_n\in Y$ and consequently, $g\in\overline{Y}$.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer. What do you think about the first part?

Comment: could you please more explain on $$h_n^{-1}\circ R_{t_n+\epsilon_n}\circ h_n\to g, \quad \text{in the } C^\infty\text{-topology}.$$

Comment: In the other words, is the "composition" a  continuous  map(not  separately but strongly in its two variables)?(In C^0 or  C^k topology?)

Comment: Thanks  again for your very interesting answer. I am sorry that I can not accept two answers:)  http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-i-can-not-accept-two-answers-on-the-same-my-question-simultaneously

Comment: @AliTaghavi the above convergence is in the $C^\infty$-topology and that implies it also converges in the $C^0$-topology.